# Concatenate two columns into one resultset column in WebSQL

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite, web-sql

I want to run this kind of a query in web sql

```
SELECT ID,
       (StartTime+EndTime) AS TimePeriod 
  FROM Department
```

Pls someone guide me. Thanks

Comment: `||` is a concat operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result:

```
   SELECT ID, 
          StartTime || EndTime AS TimePeriod 
     FROM Department
```